# The History of Linq - Any Resources?

Tags: linq

I'm interested in the history of Linq. How it was first conceived, how it grew from an idea, how it was developed to the technology it is today. Is anyone aware of a document or video that would give such a history? I know there is a Channel 9 video with Anders Hejlsberg from 2005, but this isn't what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chapter 13 of [Masterminds of Programming](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596515171) contains an interview with [Anders Hejlsberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg), one of the most prominent developers of LINQ; the linked Wikipedia entry contains links to videos with interesting background information.

Comment: @Randy: You're very welcome. On a side note: if you enjoy the book, another great interview collection can be found in "Coders at Work" (http://apress.com/book/view/1430219483, nothing on C# or LINQ in there, though).

Comment: @GregS that apress link is broken now

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis thank you, the up to date link to the "Coders at Work" book is https://www.apress.com/book/9781430219484 (I can't edit the original comment)